# contact form 7 шорткод в получателе

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Стоит плагин contact form 7 для WordPress

Есть шорткод с email адресом `[filial-email]`

В зависимости от поддомена в шорткоде меняется email адрес

Как в плагине contact form 7 указать шорткод в поле получателя?

Пробовал в лоб, указать шорткод в поле `Кому` получил ошибку:
Использован некорректный синтаксис почтового адреса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите по этой [инструкции](https://pineco.de/dynamic-author-email-with-contact-form-7/), там тоже используется шорткод в качестве поля отправки.