# Вставка шорт-кода в поле email's получаталей в плагине WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Задача: Отправить письмо о новом заказе двум получателям - самому клиенту и поставщику товара. Поставщик товара выбирается из массива в зависимости, кому принадлежит товар. Функция возвращает email нужного поставщика. С помощью шорт-кода хочу добавить получившийся email поставщика в поле адресатов.

Сам шорт-код работает в других местах - выводит email, а вот при указании в поле получателей, не отправляет письмо. Это в принципе возможно?

```
    //functions.php
    function partner_emails(){
    return 'mail@mail.ru';
}

add_shortcode( 'emails', 'partner_emails' );
```

В плагине WooCommerce во вкладке Email'ы, шаблон письма Новый Заказ в поле Получатели пишу:
client@mail.com, [emails]

Comment: похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968314/contact-form-7-%d1%88%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5/968803#968803)

Comment: @Алексей , полезно, но не совсем то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, как в данной ситуации вставить шорт-код я не понял, реализовал задачу иначе:

В файле \public_html\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\emails\class-wc-email.php есть функция: public function get_recipient(), которая вызывается в файле, отвечающем за отправку письма при новом заказе: \public_html\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\emails\class-wc-email-new-order.php
В нём я добавил пока что тестовую функцию:

```
public function partner_emails(){
    return 'mail@mail.ru';
}
```

И модифицировал функцию: public function trigger( $order_id, $order = false ) в части, где идёт отправка писем получателям:

```
if ( $this->is_enabled() && $this->get_recipient() ) {
        $this->send( $this->get_recipient().','.$this->partner_emails(), 
        $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), 
        $this->get_attachments() );
    }
```